# Updating a value that's within an array within an array in a state

Tags: reactjs, components, state

I'm trying to update the state of the id value in shoeList. Currently I have a textfield that allows for entering of a new ID and I want the state to update when the OK button is clicked.

Here is some of the relevant code:

```
state = {
    editingToggle: false,
    shoeList : [
      {name: 'bob', id: '123213-0', shoeSize: 'L'}
     ],
}

<TextInput className='text-area-header' id="textM" width="m" type="text" placeholder={this.state.shoeList[0].id}  />
<Button className="ok-button" variant="tertiary" size ='xs' type="button" handleClick={this.saveHeader}>OK</Button>

 saveHeader(e) {
    this.setState(state=> ({
     shoeList[0].name: 
    }))
    alert('Header changed to ' + this.state.shoeList[0].id);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

I'm not sure what to put in this.setState as I haven't found anything on how to update nested values through a google search. Also whenever I put a value attribute to the TextInput tags it doesn't allow me to edit in the textinput on the webpage anymore. Any help would be great

Comment: I think it's because you're not setting state correctly in saveHeader. You don't list what piece of state you're trying to update.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what to put in there tbh

Comment: You have a property but you're not setting a value to it. After the colon there is nothing.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://gist.github.com/amsterdamharu/659bb39912096e74ba1c8c676948d5d9) can help you setting nested state.[immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction) is also not too bad. And [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns/) is how to do it with es6 (it's a bit verbose so I prefer one or the other previously mentioned helpers)

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example:

```
saveHeader() {
    this.state.shoeList[0].id = 'newid'
    this.setState({ shoeList: this.state.shoeList })
}
```

setState() checks if the values have changed, and if not, it does not update the component. Changing a nested value does not change the reference to the array, which means that simply calling setState() is not enough.

There are two ways around this. The first is to use forceUpdate():

```
saveHeader() {
    this.state.shoeList[0].id = 'newid'
    this.forceUpdate()
}
```

This forces the component to re-render, even though the state didn't change.

The second way is to actually change the shoeList array by creating a new one:

```
saveHeader() {
    let newShoeList = this.state.shoeList.slice()
    newShoeList[0].id = 'newid'
    this.setState({ shoeList: newShoeList })
}
```

Using .slice() on an array creates a new array that is completely identical. But because it is a new array, React will notice that the state changed and re-render the component.

Comment: I get a TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined when I implement one of those options. I put ref="theTextInput" on the <input></input> element and replaced 'newid' with this.refs.theTextInput.shoeList[0].id. It works if it's just 'newid' but this.refs.theTextInput.shoeList[0].id causes the error and I don't know why lol

Comment: The error means that shoeList is not a property on theTextInput. I don't see why it would, and also why would you want to access it that way?

Comment: i just want the state value to update with whatever is in the text input. I looked up some tutorials and it seemed like that was the way to do it by referring to the ref on the input element. How would I go about setting the state based on whats currently in the input element then?

Comment: To access the value you should do this.refs.theTextInput.value instead. Like: newShoeList[0].id = this.refs.theTextInput.value

Comment: Never use assignment to `state` outside of the constructor. Always use `setState` unless you want to fix bugs later. `setState({ ...this.state, key: "newValue" });`.

Comment: That worked Viktor thank you so much. Also for taystacks comment, I tried doing saveHeader() {
      this.setState({
        ...this.state.shoeList[0], 
        name: this.refs.theTextInput.value})
  } but it doesn't seem to work. How would I access the value thats nested within the arrays?

Comment: @taystack Yeah in general its bad practice. Therefore I would say my second alternative is better. (also, you shouldn't do ...state in setState, since React only updates the properties that are included in the update object. Doing so could actually introduce bugs)